# Rails: Check if Profile applied for job

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application where a Profile applies for jobs. There is a has_many through relationship between Jobs and Profiles where all the Relationships get saved on a table called "Relationships".

Let's say a Profile visits a job. How can I check if there's a relationship between that profile (current_profile) and the job he's viewing?

Models associations:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :relationships , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :jobs, through: :relationships
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employer
  has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :profiles, through: :relationships
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :job
end
```

Comment: Please post your model associations

Comment: hi, I just updated the question

Comment: Do you try something similar: `current_user.profile.jobs.where(id: current_job_id).any?`

Comment: Gosh, that worked! this is my first "complex" Rails app. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just check current_profile.jobs.present?

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple just check if id of current_profile is exist in relationship
for e.g
if Relationship.all.include? current_profile.id

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @kunashir worked. I just had to check:

```
current_user.profile.jobs.where(id: current_job_id).any?
```